How to only inject one parameter in a constructor (the rest being normal parameters)?
How to only inject one parameter in a constructor?
Having a class like this:
@AndroidEntryPoint 
class CustomClass @Inject constructor (val repository: Repository, val name: String) {}

Let's say I only want to inject the repository parameter, but I want to pass the name parameter during initialization like so:
val customClass = CustomClass("name")

How to do it?

Probably you are looking for an "Assisted Injection".

Use @AssistedInject instead of @Inject for constructor injection.
Arguments which need to be provided at runtime are annotated with @Assisted.

Now, after doing the above changes still we can’t directly inject CustomClass, we first need to create a factory for it because we will use that factory to create an instance of the actual class.

We annotate our factory with @AssistedFactory. This annotation tells the Hilt that this interface is used to create an instance of a class that requires Assisted Injection.

Inside this factory, we create a function named “create” that will be responsible for returning an instance of CustomClass and accepts only those arguments which are to be provided/assisted by us at runtime (i.e. name) that means arguments annotated as @Assisted.


Now we will create a factory provider function named providesFactory() which will provide instance of CustomClass. Note that providesFactory() function will require assistedFactory & all the assisted arguments to be supplied at runtime.
class CustomClass @AssistedInject constructor(
    val repository: Repository,
    @Assisted val name: String
) {

    @AssistedFactory
    interface CustomClassFactory {
        fun create(name: String): CustomClass
    }

    companion object {
        fun providesFactory(
            assistedFactory: CustomClassFactory,
            name: String
        ): CustomClass = assistedFactory.create(name)
    }
}

An @AssistedInject constructor looks very similar to an @Inject constructor. However, there are some important differences.

@AssistedInject types cannot be injected directly, only the @AssistedFactory type can be injected. This is true even if the constructor does not contain any assisted parameters.
@AssistedInject types cannot be scoped.

@AndroidEntryPoint
class CustomActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var customClassFactory: CustomClass.CustomClassFactory

    private val customClass: CustomClass by lazy {
        CustomClass.providesFactory(customClassFactory, "CustomClass")
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        println(customClass.name)
    }
}


wow, too much boilerplate complexity just for passing parameters to a class

Following the dagger documentation here
What you can do is using the @AssistedInject annotation and create a factory to be used.
class CustomClass @AssisgtedInject constructor (
    val repository: Repository, 
    @Assisted val name: String
) {

    @AssistedFactory
    interface CustomClassFactory {
        fun create(name: String): CustomClass
    }
}

Then you can have the @Inject CustomClassFactory and call the CustomClassFactory.create() to create your object.

wow, too much boilerplate complexity just for passing parameters to a class

Don't inject the constructer. Instead create a normal constructor and only inject the repository.
@AndroidEntryPoint 
class CustomClass(val name: String) {

    @Inject
    lateinit val repository: Repository
}


nice, but unfortunatelly seems to not work with viewmodel

I guess you should not put the name String directly into the viewmodel. Consider making it a parameter of your View or put it into another dependency like the Repo.
